# Can mystic Gohan hold his own against Goku Super Saiyan Blue?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the week prior to episode 90th, where Gohan was going to have a training fight against Goku in Super Saiyan Blue, a japanese magazine gave an advancement saying this was going to happen and that mystic Gohan was going to be able to hold his own against Super Saiyan Blue Goku. But in episode 90th what we've seen..

> it's Gohan having an even match with Goku in base form. Later Gohan having an even match against Goku in SSJ2. Later a very brief fight between mystic Gohan vs Goku Super Saiyan Blue and finally Goku defeating Gohan using Super Saiyan Blue Kaioken.

Therefore, can it be said mystic Gohan can hold his own against Goku Super Saiyan Blue ? is he even or is he weaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think he is probably weaker, if you look closely at the fight when SSB Goku and Ultimate Gohan clash Goku seems to shrug off the two punches Gohan lands, but when a Goku lands one punch on Gohan he is visibly hurt and shaken. I would assume Ultimate form Gohan at this point is 60-70%  SSB Goku max since Goku wouldn't hold back after seeing his son like that.

Comment: He could have gone more gradually like turning into SSJ3 and see if Gohan can handle that. Or turning super saiyan god red, I still wonder if it exists by its own in the anime or only can be achieved alone without the ritual in the manga.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be yes. Holding his own doesn't imply him being able to straight up defeat Goku. I'd say Full power mystic Gohan might be stronger than SSJG Goku and can probably hold his own against SSJB like android 17. Although, it's likely Android 17 might be stronger considering Gohan had to ask Goku to use SSJB while Goku went SSJB on his own against 17. Also the fact that Gohan managed to survive an attack from SSJB Kaioken which is strong enough to easily kill Gohan and destroy him shows that he can clearly hold his own against SSJB. Although, If Goku were to go all out right from the start while using SSJB, Gohan wouldn't stand a chance.

Answer (score 0):

An answer for the manga continuity (which is different from the anime continuity) from chapter #39. Mystic Gohan can not only hold his own against Super Saiyan Blue, at that point it's stronger than it. Mystic Gohan is about the same level of Kefla, which is the fusion of Kale and Caulifla, being Kale able to defeat Aniraza and to fight Goku SSB and Golden Freezer at the same time. So since the fusion is "tens of times stronger" than the original fighters according to Wiss's words, Mystic Gohan has to be "tens of times" stronger than Super Saiyan Blue Goku who wasnt stronger than Kale.